# FreeBSD 8.2 + Apache 2.2 + mod_auth_pam2: unable to authenticate

Tags: apache-2.2, freebsd, pam

I've installed Apache 2.2 and `mod_auth_pam2` from ports, but I can't get local UNIX authentication to work. When I access the protected part of my local website, I do get the authentication request, and with `pam_permit.so`, it works. However, when I change `pam_permit.so` to the real thing, `pam_unix.so`, I get this message in `httpd-error.log`:

```
[error] PAM: user 'foo' - not authenticated: authentication error
```

This is the relevant part of my Apache config, though I don't think it's the problem as PAM obviously works:

```
<Location /foo>
    AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
    AuthPAM_Enabled on
    AuthPAM_FallThrough off
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Secret place"
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

This is my `/etc/pam.d/httpd`, though I don't think it's the problem either, since it works with `pam_permit.so`:

```
auth    required    pam_unix.so
account required    pam_unix.so
```

So what am I missing? What does it take to have `pam_unix.so` work for `httpd` under FreeBSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what was the problem; I think it's because `www` didn't have access to `/etc/passwd`. I thought it was a horrible idea to grant it this access (even for just trying), so instead I removed `mod_auth_pam2` and installed `mod_authnz_external` with `pwauth`, both from ports. It also has the notable advantage of being an `authnz` module (rather than an `auth` module), playing better with the latest versions of Apache. Works like a charm!

This is my new (relevant) httpd config:

```
AddExternalAuth pwauth /usr/local/bin/pwauth
SetExternalAuthMethod pwauth pipe

<Location /foo>        
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Secret place"
        AuthBasicProvider external
        AuthExternal pwauth
        Require valid-user
        Require group wheel
</Location>
```

And `/etc/pam.d/pwauth`:

```
auth    required    pam_unix.so
account required    pam_unix.so
```

Comment: Be absolutely sure you add some sort of rate limiting mechanism, like fail2ban, or any script kiddie can brute force your passwords and is only limited by your processor and/or bandwidth speeds.

Comment: @Chris S, that's useful advice for people having the same problem for servers that face the Internet (and I'd like to add that in such a situation, it would be worthwhile to use `https` instead since a sniffed password could compromise the box). In the actual configuration file, though, I also limit the access to this part of my site to machines on the local network, so I'm not worried about script kiddies.

Comment: Limiting it to your network definitely works. Adding HTTPS would be pretty useless against script kiddies, and isn't necessary to prevent sniffed passwords.